# Python. Color coding elements for scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simulation set up for traffic flow and i require a visualisation of the system for which ive used a scatter plot. I am looking for a way to give each element in my array a different color but one that is constant as my program loops

Comment: Please post an example of your output data and a mockup of how you want the resulting visualization to appear. Show us also what you tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can set the colour of scatter plot points using `c=...` in the call to `scatter`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [10, 11, 12, 11, 9]
z = [2, 4, 4, 1, 1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, linewidth=0)

plt.show()
```

To give each point its own colour simply use `range(len(x))` for the colours:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [10, 11, 12, 11, 9]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x, y, c=range(len(x)), linewidth=0)

plt.show()
```

[image: Scatter plot with different colours]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [`plt.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) documentation, one finds that the `c` argument can be used for setting the color of the scatter points.

> ```
> c : color, sequence, or sequence of color, optional, default: ‘b’  
>     c can be a single color format string, or a sequence of color specifications  
>     of length N, or a sequence of N numbers to be mapped to colors using  
>     the cmap and norm specified via kwargs (see below).
> ```

So, in order to obtain a constant color for each scatter point, there are two options:

#### Specify an absolute color

```
plt.scatter(x,y, c=["blue", "red", "green"])
```

#### Specify a value to be colormapped according to a normalization

```
plt.scatter(x,y, c=[3.4, 5.6, 7.9, 1.0], cmap="jet", vmin=0, vmax=10)
```

or using a Normalize instance

```
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=10)
plt.scatter(x,y, c=[3.4, 5.6, 7.9, 1.0], cmap="jet", norm=norm)
```

Without the normalization, the colors from the colormap would be distributed according the the minimum and maximum value in the array that is given to `c`.